# Communicating with I2C devices using an RTL8710

Tags: i2c

I've connected an RTL8710 ([in "Rtlduino" form](https://cdn.tindiemedia.com/images/resize/0Ybv4cqLGZzr93d9ArHMqoBQydo=/p/fit-in/653x435/filters:fill(fff)/i/42304/products/2016-11-03T02%3A01%3A54.731Z-9277.2.jpg)) to a MCP23008 (on a breadboard) via I2C as follows:

[image: My setup]

I'm using [rustl8710](https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710) to program the RTL8710, which works fine and I've already hooked up a display via SPI without any issues.

I've got this code set up to test the MCP23008:

```
led1.write(DigitalValue::High);
let mut handle = i2c_t::default();
i2c_init(&mut handle as *mut i2c_t, PinName::PC_4, PinName::PC_5);
i2c_frequency(&mut handle as *mut i2c_t, 1000);
led2.write(DigitalValue::High);
if i2c_write(&mut handle as *mut i2c_t, 0x20, &[ 0x00, 0xff as i8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ][0] as *const i8, 11, 1) != 1
{
    panic!("Byte write failed!");
}

led3.write(DigitalValue::High);
loop { }
```

Feel free to ignore all lines starting with `led*`, those simply pull some GPIO pins high to light up the 3 internal LEDs on the device so I can see if it works without using `gdb`.

Alternatively, this C code demonstrates the same problem:

```
#include "i2c_api.h"
#include "PinNames.h"

void main(void)
{
    ConfigDebugInfo = 0xffffffff;

    char data[] = { 0x00, 0xff, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    i2c_t handle;
    i2c_init(&handle, PC_4, PC_5);
    i2c_frequency(&handle, 1000);
    i2c_write(&handle, 0x20, data, 11, 1);

    while(1) { }
}
```

Paste the code above in place of `main` in [`main.c`](https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710/blob/master/src/c/src/main.c) and then flash and run the code using `make && make flash && make debug`. The code will never reach the `while` loop, and hang on `i2c_write`.

The code effectively does the same thing as [this code in an Adafruit library for the MCP23008](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23008-library/blob/master/Adafruit_MCP23008.cpp#L46).

I2C set-up (first 5 lines) works, but when calling `i2c_write` the RTL8710 just hangs infinitely somewhere in a loop in [`RtkI2CSend_Patch () at component/soc/realtek/8195a/fwlib/src/hal_i2c.c:1324`](https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710/blob/master/component/soc/realtek/8195a/fwlib/src/hal_i2c.c#L1324) (according to `gdb`)

The MCP23008 is working fine, I've successfully used that on an ATTiny85.

Other things that might be relevant:

- PC_5 (aka GC5) is also connected to a button on the evaluation board, which pulls the pin high when it's *not* pressed.
- The RTL8710 prints `RTL8195A[HAL]: ISR 0 didb't bee register!!!␊` to the UART_LOG ports. This appears to be [from a function](https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710/blob/master/component/soc/realtek/8195a/fwlib/src/hal_i2c.c#L2374) that isn't available in source form so I'm not quite sure how I should interpret that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you include a minimum working example that shows the problem? In case someone wants to test this, they will struggle with above code. I can't find out where your i2c_* are from. Why is frequency 1kHz (datasheet lists 100kHz as min)? Why is there a `0xff as i8` (doesn't rustc warn about this)?

Comment: @domen sure thing. The code I posted is basically already the full code, but I'll expand it to a full example with some instructions on how to run it. The I2C API is located here: https://github.com/lupyuen/rustl8710/blob/master/component/common/mbed/targets/hal/rtl8195a/i2c_api.c , `0xff as i8` is needed because the C type of i2c_write requires an array of `char`s, and `char`s are signed in C. `0xff` is not interpreted as a i8 without that cast.

Comment: @domen I'm fairly sure the 100kHz is an upper limit, and not a minimum. I've tested the MCP23008 using bitbanged i2c which had an average frequency of around 50Hz and a clock all over the place and that still worked without issues.

Comment: Signedness of `char` in C is implementation defined, so it's definitely weird to see them used for non-string characters. Does I2C work for you with any other i2c devices on rtl8710? Have you got access to oscilloscope/logical probe? Might be worth opening a ticket for rtl8710 i2c code.

Comment: @domen that would indeed be what I'll probably have to do eventually, but I was just hoping someone had run into this issue before. I've tried to use a Raspberry Pi to print something if the SCL or SDA lines go low, which never seems to happen (or the pi isn't accurate enough)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I was indeed not the only one to notice this issue. In both the 3.5a and 4.0b SDKs (rustl8710 is using the 3.5a SDK), there is a bug in the I2C code. Realtek have released a fix for this bug, but *this fix is not included in the SDK downloads, nor listed on the download page, nor listed in the release notes*.

Instead, you have to download a fixed library from the FAQ page here: https://www.amebaiot.com/en/ameba-sdk-faq/. For rustl8710, which uses the 3.5a SDK, you'd click on 'Fix 3.5a GCC SDK I2C problem', then download the linked zip file (note: you might need to create an account before you can download the file). This zip file contains a single `lib_platform.a`, which you'll have to copy over the existing file in `component/soc/realtek/8195a/misc/bsp/lib/common/GCC/lib_platform.a`.

After this, use these `make` commands to rebuild everything:

```
make clean
make
```

For me, I2C still doesn't work the first time after flashing. This can be worked around by starting a debug session using `make debug`, then quitting using `q` and restarting the debug session using `make debug` again.